# Trying to exit C# Excel Workbook without a dialog box

Tags: c#, excel-interop, excel-automation

I am using Microsoft Office Interop to edit some excel files and when I close them I use

```
outputExcelWorkBook.Close(false, paramMissing, paramMissing);
```

But a dialog box still comes up, even though I passed `false` as the first parameter. I have also tried it with `true` and giving it a file path as the second parameter but in both cases a dialog box comes up asking me if I want to save before closing. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting the `Application.DisplayAlerts` property to `false`. You may find it useful to set this property to `false` for the majority of your automation routines. Remember to restore the previous value before returning.

```
Application applicationInstance = ...;
var oldDisplayAlertsValue = applicationInstance.DisplayAlerts;
applicationInstance.DisplayAlerts = false;
try
{
    outputExcelWorkBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
}
finally
{
    appliationInstance.DisplayAlerts = oldDisplayAlertsValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Initiate Excel
2. Open the workbook
3. Get the active sheet and make an edit (added "Text" to cell [2,2])
4. Close the workbook with a single parameter of true which means "save changes"
5. No dialog box is displayed.

Note: When I call Close without a parameter I am prompted to save changes.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook =
        excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = workBook.ActiveSheet;
    sheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Text";
    workBook.Close(true);
    excel.Quit();
```