# Closing Excel application with Excel Interop without save message

Tags: c#, excel, com, excel-interop

I am working with Excel Interop COM object.
I am writing a method in which I am opening and closing an Excel application followed by opening an Excel workbook and sheet. After I'm done working on them I am closing both the application and workbook. 
My problem is that this method can be called repeatedly several times and when the sheet and app are closing I get from the Excel application a message if I want to save the changes I've made. The method get stuck until I press "No" but I can't tell the user to press it every time.

How can I close the application without receiving this message or at least answer it by code?

These are the methods I'm using to close the application and workbook:

```
private void FreeWorkSheetResources(Excel.Worksheet sheet)
{
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
  sheet = null;
}

private void FreeWorkBookResources()
{
  if (_excelSheets != null)
  {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_excelSheets);
    _excelSheets = null;
  }
  _excelWorkBook.Close();
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_excelWorkBook);
  _excelWorkBook = null;
}

private void FreeApplicationResources()
{
  _app.Quit();
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_app);
  _app = null;
  GC.Collect();
}
```

And this is the way I'm using them:

```
if (_app == null)
  {
    _app = new Excel.Application();
  }
  if (_excelWorkBook == null)
  {
    _excelWorkBook = GetWorkBook(_filePath);
  }
  ....
  ....
  FreeWorkBookResources();
  FreeApplicationResources();
```

Comment: so you are not saving the changes which you are making on worksheet right?

Comment: I am only reading from the worksheet, not updating it. I don't know why he's even asking me if I want to save any changes

Comment: Duplicate of [Trying to exit C# Excel Workbook without a dialog box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413887/trying-to-exit-c-sharp-excel-workbook-without-a-dialog-box). Please use the search.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While Closing Your Excel WorkBook you can use following Statements:

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
```

Comment: You actually do not even need to create a variable. The following works for me: xlWorkBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

Answer (score 5):

My problem was similar. I needed to generate Excel Sheet, then convert it to PDF. My problem was that the Excel App was displaying and notifying me to save before Exit. The solution was setting `.Visible = flase` and `.DisplayAlerts = False`

Thanks to @adil

Comment: This worked for me! The syntax was "myExcel.Visible = false; myExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False;
//save and close your workbook
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = True;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this when closing workbook.

```
_excelWorkBook.Close(true);
```

Comment: This worked for me.  The accepted answer corrupted my file (idk how).

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue where the save dialog box was still displaying after opening and reading an Excel file without edit.

Setting

```
xlApplication.Visible = false;
xlApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

and closing the workbook with the SaveChanges parameter as false

```
xlWorkbook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

didn't work either.  I was working with an Excel file type of .xlsb (binary with macros), when I saved as .xlsx (without macros) the .Close method worked.  Saving as .xslm (xslx with macros) gave me the same problem of the save dialog displaying.

I turned to the MS support site on VBA for Excel and found this article, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213428/how-to-suppress-save-changes-prompt-when-you-close-a-workbook-in-excel detailing how to accomplish the close without save in a VBA macro.  Adapting to C# I explicitly set the Saved property to true.  The below worked for me using .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb file types.

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        var xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileInfo.FullName);

        // do work

        xlWorkbook.Saved = true;
        xlWorkbook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        xlApp.Quit();
```