# Reading Excel XLTM files programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, excel-2010

I need to read XLTM files without opening it.

With Excel interop, i can read but it will open the file too.

The below link shows reading xlsx file with OLDB. But same wont work for XLTM.

http://codehill.com/2009/01/reading-excel-2003-and-2007-files-using-oledb/

Is there any way i can read XLTM file with out opening the file it self.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use the Excel interop assembly, just set **visibility** and **screenUpdation** off like :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xltmApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xltmApp.Visible = false;
xltmApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
Workbook xltmBook = xltmApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test.xltm");
...do stuff
```

Then close document properly see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1e33e36.aspx

Also if you want you can turn off dialog boxes during saving see: [Trying to exit C# Excel Workbook without a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413887/trying-to-exit-c-sharp-excel-workbook-without-a-dialog-box).