# How to disable the prompt dialog when I save the excel file created using C# while conflict occurs?

Tags: c#, excel

I create a excel file using C#, and set the `ConflictResolution` parameter to`Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges` in `SaveAs()` function.

I also set the `app.UserControl` to false, but the prompt dialog will always show up.

what should I do to disable the dialog

```
string fileName = "f:\\ok.xlsx";

object missing = Type.Missing;

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
app.Visible = false;
app.UserControl = false;
Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Add(missing);
Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
sheet.Name = "s1";
sheet.Cells[1 , 1] = "id";
book.SaveAs(fileName , Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault ,
            missing , missing , missing , missing ,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange ,
            Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges ,
            missing , missing , missing , missing);
book.Close(missing , missing , missing);
app.Quit();
```

Comment: A couple of sources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575117/how-to-disable-popups-when-opening-a-file-using-microsoft-office-interop , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413887/trying-to-exit-c-sharp-excel-workbook-without-a-dialog-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to disable Excel's alerts when writing a file, simply use `.DisplayAlerts = false;`

Example code that I currently use to save my Excel files:

```
public void SaveExcelFile(Excel.Application app, string exportPath)
{
    try
    {
        //Stops from asking to overwrite
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Excel._Worksheet sheet = app.ActiveSheet;

        //Save and close
        sheet.SaveAs(exportPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //If something fails, show the error
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Failed to save Excel file! " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Makes sure that there aren't any lingering Excel processes
        app.Quit();
    }
}
```

Works like a charm for me. The important part of this snippet is the `app.DisplayAlerts = false;` line. This will stop from asking if you want to save the file or overwrite an existing file of the same name. If you aren't wanting to overwrite files automatically in a fear of losing data, then I don't recommend disabling the alerts.

Note: wrapping it all in a `try-catch` isn't always the best practice. For the complexity of the program that uses this method, I know where the error may occur (`.SaveAs(exportPath);` in case the supplied `exportPath` doesn't exist or is a mistype or whatever other reason for it to throw the error). Would probably be best to only wrap the `sheet.SaveAs(exportPath);` in the `try-catch` just to be certain.